# how to install ffmpeg on localhost

Tags: php, windows, apache, dll, ffmpeg

There is a lot of topics on this but after hours of reading i am still getting no where.
I have found a lot of issues wit this.

1. people have given links to files that no longer exist
2. the help people have given refers to files that aren't included with the download

This is the nearest i have found

[link](http://sergey89.ru/files/ffmpeg-php-win32-all.zip)

I followed this exactly, after finding a different version of the file [broken link](https://rapidshare.com/#!download%7C934l34%7C422916798%7Cphp_ffmpeg_v0.6.0_for_PHP_5.3.1.rar)

[version I found](http://sergey89.ru/files/ffmpeg-php-win32-all.zip) version available at [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/files/) which isn't very helpful.

Steps as decribed:

1. unzip
2. copy ffmpeg.exe somewhere and remember the path for later use
3. move php_ffmpeg.dll to php extension dir (usually c:\xampp\php\ext)
4. move all other files to Windows\System32 (except COPYING.GPLv3.txt,
   readme.txt)
5. add extension=php_ffmpeg.dll to php.ini (usually
   c:\xampp\php\php.ini)
6. restart apache with fingers crossed questions/answers
   http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=41913

But when I restart apache I get the error:

The program can't because avcodec-51.dll is missing

AND

PHP startup: Unable to load dynamic libary php_ffmpeg.dll can't be found

The php_ffmpeg file is in the apache extention folder and has been declared in the php.ini file. I don't really change many settings in my php.ini file so I just put iy at the top of the extentions, if this is the problem please let me know.

extension=php_ffmpeg.dll  <---first extention added
extension=php_bz2.dll    <---- this was allready there

If anybody knows an easy way to install this on a localhost I would really appropriate and if I'm having this much trouble on localhost should I bother trying to get this working on my lunix server.

(I am using xampp on windows and my lunix server is hosted through 1and1 - not my first choice but its for a friends site)

Comment: i managed to sort it but don't really use it as a lot of web hosting companies don't have it installed on their servers.

Comment: and then what is your solution to convert videos online?